# VB runtime error 438 on running vbscript on Excel file

Tags: vba, runtime-error

Hi I am getting VB runtime Error code 438 and on debugging it points to below code line. I'm not sure whats wrong as this is automated script that was working earlier

```
Private Sub ResetView() ' Resetting the view to the default.
    
    InitGlobalCst
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Untoggle the "MultiSearch buttons here.
    **Sheets("Views").Multi_Case.Value = False**
    Sheets("Views").Multi_CR.Value = False
```

Comment: What version of VB does this question actually relate to? You've tagged it VB.NET, you say that you're running VBScript but you also mention Excel, which suggests VBA. Try providing a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. You should have taken the site tour when prompted, as it is supposed to help you learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Are you sure that there is still a control on the sheet with the name `Multi_CR`? If it got deleted or renamed then the code will fail with that error.